# Incorrect return in levenshtien distance algorithm

Tags: java

This is levenshtien algorithm in dynamic programming strategy. In my code when str1 want convert to str2 must changed.Insertion 1 char has 2 cost and delete 1 char cost 1.The example of code must print 2 but print 1.why?Thanks for any help.

```
public class Distance {
    static int min(int x,int y)
    {
        if (x < y ) return x;
        else return y;
    }

    static int editDistDP(String str1, String str2, int m, int n)
    {
        int dp[][] = new int[m+1][n+1];

        for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
            {
                if (i==0)
                    dp[i][j] = j;  // Min. operations = j

                else if (j==0)
                    dp[i][j] = i; // Min. operations = i

                else if (str1.charAt(i-1) == str2.charAt(j-1))
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];

                else
                    dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j-1] + 2,  // Insert
                            dp[i-1][j] + 1);  // Remove
            }
        }

        return dp[m][n];
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str1 = "pple";
        String str2 = "apple";
        System.out.println( editDistDP( str1 , str2 , str1.length(), str2.length()) );
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger to find it out

Comment: I have learned Dynamic programming recently and this is a littel complex